# How to transition between screens in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Today I started learning how to develop for Windows Phone, and I have a question.

I have a main screen (MainPage.xaml) and a second screen (TaskPage.xaml).
I want to navigate between these screens.

I wrote:

```
        var frame = Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
        frame.Source = new Uri("/TaskPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
```

I ran it in the emulator, but visual studio return an error in MainPage.g.i.is in line:

```
   System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, new System.Uri("/Appname;component/MainPage.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative));
```

Whats wrong? Sorry for bad english and thanks for answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making use of the NavigationService such as:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/TaskPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

In your current code where you were changing the frame.Source.  For a bigger picture on navigation in WP7 give this a read through : [WP7 Navigation Step by Step](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-7-Navigation-Transitions-Step-By-Step-guide)